# How would to make this class as a singleton?

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface, singleton, oboe

I'm trying to make this class as a singleton but without success.
How would you do that ?
I have seen out there on internet that I should make modifications to the header file and to the cpp file. I've tried only by changing the cpp file...
What I need to do is to be able to access the boolean "isRecording" from JNI calls.

Thanks.

OboeAudioRecorder.cpp

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <string>
#include <oboe/Oboe.h>
#include "OboeAudioRecorder.h"
#include "oboe/samples/debug-utils/logging_macros.h"

class OboeAudioRecorder: public oboe::AudioStreamCallback {
public:
    bool isRecording = true;

    explicit OboeAudioRecorder() { }

    void StartAudioRecorder() {
        oboe::AudioStreamBuilder builder;
        builder.setDirection(oboe::Direction::Input);
        builder.setPerformanceMode(oboe::PerformanceMode::LowLatency);
        builder.setFormat(oboe::AudioFormat::Float);
        builder.setChannelCount(oboe::ChannelCount::Mono);
        builder.setInputPreset(oboe::InputPreset::Unprocessed);
        builder.setSharingMode(oboe::SharingMode::Shared);
        builder.setSampleRate(48000);
        builder.setAudioApi(oboe::AudioApi::OpenSLES);
        //builder.setCallback(this);

        oboe::Result r = builder.openStream(&stream);
        if (r != oboe::Result::OK) {
            return;
        }

        r = stream->requestStart();
        if (r != oboe::Result::OK) {
            return;
        }

        auto a = stream->getState();
        if (a == oboe::StreamState::Started) {

            constexpr int kMillisecondsToRecord = 2;
            const int32_t requestedFrames = (int32_t) (kMillisecondsToRecord * (stream->getSampleRate() / oboe::kMillisPerSecond));
            __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "OboeAudioRecorder", "requestedFrames = %d", requestedFrames);
            float_t mybuffer[requestedFrames];
            constexpr int64_t kTimeoutValue = 3 * oboe::kNanosPerMillisecond;

            int framesRead = 0;
            do {
                auto result = stream->read(mybuffer, requestedFrames, 0);
                if (result != oboe::Result::OK) {
                    break;
                }
                framesRead = result.value();
                __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "OboeAudioRecorder", "framesRead = %d", framesRead);
                if (framesRead > 0) {
                    break;
                }
            } while (framesRead != 0);

            while (isRecording) {
                auto result = stream->read(mybuffer, requestedFrames, kTimeoutValue * 1000);
                if (result == oboe::Result::OK) {
                    auto nbFramesRead = result.value();
                    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "OboeAudioRecorder", "nbFramesRead = %d", nbFramesRead);
                    for (int i=0; i<nbFramesRead; i++) {
                        __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "OboeAudioRecorder", "nbFramesRead[%d] = %f", i, mybuffer[i]);
                    }
                } else {
                    auto error = convertToText(result.error());
                    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "OboeAudioRecorder", "error = %s", error);
                }
            }

            stream->requestStop();
            stream->close();
        }
    }

    oboe::DataCallbackResult onAudioReady(oboe::AudioStream *oboeStream, void *audioData, int32_t numFrames) override {
        LOGE("onAudioReady");
    }

private:
    oboe::ManagedStream outStream;
    oboe::AudioStream *stream{};
};
```

OboeAudioRecorder.h

```
#ifndef OBOEAUDIORECORDER_OBOEAUDIORECORDER_H
#define OBOEAUDIORECORDER_OBOEAUDIORECORDER_H


#endif //OBOEAUDIORECORDER_OBOEAUDIORECORDER_H
```

Comment: WHat's the point of that empty header? Also, what's preventing your JNI code from having access to an instance of `OboeAudioRecorder`?

Comment: What I need is a singleton instance. My JNI code works fine with a simple instance of OboeAudioRecorder but I would like it to be a singleton in order to access it from 2 separate JNI functions (one which sets the isRecording boolean to true and one which sets the isRecording boolean to false). The empty header has been generated by Android studio automatically.

Comment: Well, then look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1008019/c-singleton-design-pattern  Though I still don't understand from your description why a singleton is needed.

Comment: Ok I'll have a look at the link you posted. What I need is only one instance of OboeAudioRecorder, because I must have control over the isRecording boolean of the initially created instance of OboeAudioRecorder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been able to make this class a singleton, thanks to the following link (in french) : https://h-deb.clg.qc.ca/Sujets/Divers--cplusplus/CPP--Singletons.html

Here is my class with the singleton pattern (notice the last line that is declared out of the "class" scope) :

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <string>
#include <oboe/Oboe.h>
#include "OboeAudioRecorder.h"
#include "oboe/samples/debug-utils/logging_macros.h"

class OboeAudioRecorder: public oboe::AudioStreamCallback {

private:
    oboe::ManagedStream outStream;
    oboe::AudioStream *stream{};

    oboe::DataCallbackResult
    onAudioReady(oboe::AudioStream *oboeStream, void *audioData, int32_t numFrames) override {
        LOGE("onAudioReady");
    }

    static OboeAudioRecorder *singleton;
    explicit OboeAudioRecorder() = default;

public:
    static OboeAudioRecorder *get() {
        if (!singleton)
            singleton = new OboeAudioRecorder();
        return singleton;
    }

    bool isRecording = true;

    void StartAudioRecorder() {
        oboe::AudioStreamBuilder builder;
        builder.setDirection(oboe::Direction::Input);
        builder.setPerformanceMode(oboe::PerformanceMode::LowLatency);
        //builder.setFormat(oboe::AudioFormat::Float);
        builder.setFormat(oboe::AudioFormat::I16);
        builder.setChannelCount(oboe::ChannelCount::Mono);
        builder.setInputPreset(oboe::InputPreset::Unprocessed);
        builder.setSharingMode(oboe::SharingMode::Shared);
        builder.setSampleRate(48000);
        builder.setAudioApi(oboe::AudioApi::OpenSLES);
        //builder.setCallback(this);

        oboe::Result r = builder.openStream(&stream);
        if (r != oboe::Result::OK) {
            return;
        }

        r = stream->requestStart();
        if (r != oboe::Result::OK) {
            return;
        }

        auto a = stream->getState();
        if (a == oboe::StreamState::Started) {

            constexpr int kMillisecondsToRecord = 2;
            auto requestedFrames = (int32_t) (kMillisecondsToRecord *
                                                       (stream->getSampleRate() /
                                                        oboe::kMillisPerSecond));
            __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "OboeAudioRecorder", "requestedFrames = %d",
                                requestedFrames);
            //const int32_t requestedFrames = 65536;
            //int16_t mybuffer[requestedFrames];
            int16_t mybuffer[requestedFrames];
            constexpr int64_t kTimeoutValue = 3 * oboe::kNanosPerMillisecond;

            int framesRead = 0;
            do {
                auto result = stream->read(mybuffer, requestedFrames, 0);
                if (result != oboe::Result::OK) {
                    break;
                }
                framesRead = result.value();
                __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "OboeAudioRecorder", "framesRead = %d",
                                    framesRead);
                if (framesRead > 0) {
                    break;
                }
            } while (framesRead != 0);

            while (isRecording) {
                auto result = stream->read(mybuffer, requestedFrames, kTimeoutValue * 1000);
                if (result == oboe::Result::OK) {
                    auto nbFramesRead = result.value();
                    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "OboeAudioRecorder", "nbFramesRead = %d",
                                        nbFramesRead);
                    for (int i = 0; i < nbFramesRead; i++) {
                        __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "OboeAudioRecorder",
                                            "nbFramesRead[%d] = %d", i, mybuffer[i]);
                    }
                } else {
                    auto error = convertToText(result.error());
                    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "OboeAudioRecorder", "error = %s", error);
                }
            }

            stream->requestStop();
            stream->close();
        }
    }


};

OboeAudioRecorder *OboeAudioRecorder::singleton = nullptr;
```

Answer (score 2):

An easy way to make a class into a singleton is to add a getInstance() method that uses a static variable in the method.

```
static OboeAudioRecorder &getInstance() {
    static EngineOpenSLES sInstance;
    return sInstance;
}
```

You can also prevent other instances from being created by making the constructors private and by deleting the copy operators:

```
private:
    // Make this a safe Singleton
    OboeAudioRecorder()= default;
    ~OboeAudioRecorder()= default;
public:
    OboeAudioRecorder(const OboeAudioRecorder&)= delete;
    OboeAudioRecorder& operator=(const OboeAudioRecorder&)= delete;
```